# Take an array input using a generic function in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, initialization, utility

what I am trying to do is, I have a UTILITY package and I wanted to make a class GetArray with a method get, which creates an array and return that array, also *I wanted to make this method* `generic` so I could create what ever type of array I wanted to.

The problem is in the statement `arr[i] = in.next();` in the loop.
*ie, how would I assign values depending on the type of the array I want to build*

```
public class GetArray {

    /**
     * @param takes a scanner varable
     * @return returns an array of all the elements you specify
     */

    public static <T> int[] get(Scanner in) {

        System.out.print("enter array size :  ");
        int ar_size = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("arr elements: ");
        T arr[] = new T[ar_size];

        for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.next();
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

I will be calling this method from my main.java, and therefore I am passing the scanner to it

Comment: "how would I assign values depending on the type of the array I want to build" You need to pass in a `Function<Integer, T[]>` to create the array, and a `Function<String, T>` to parse the string to a `T`.

Comment: Scanner.next always returns a string http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Scanner.java#line-1349 so this generics would fail, because the type always needs to be a type of string.

Comment: @nathan I deleted my answer because as you pointed out I didn't understand the question

Comment: hey @AndyTurner  can you plz give the code,(or change my code) that will be very helpful thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have generic array then you have to modify your code like this

```
      public class GetArray {

/**
 * @param takes a scanner varable
 * @return returns an array of all the elements you specify
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] get(Scanner in) {

    System.out.print("enter array size :  ");
    int ar_size = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("arr elements: ");
    Object arr[] =  new Object[ar_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
        arr[i] =  (T)in.next();
    }
    return (T[]) arr;
}
```

}

Comment: you have to return the complete array and you can't create a generic type of array so you need to create an array of objects and then typecast it to generics. I hope this works

Comment: it will, except that there will be no runtime type checking on the element type.

Comment: I did not add any checking as there is no **demand** for it in the question

Comment: What I meant, is that you will be able to put any type of object in the array, whereas had the array been created with the correct element type, this would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

To have the correct array type, you need to pass the class of the elements:

```
public static <T> T[] get(Scanner in, Class<T> clazz) {

    System.out.print("enter array size :  ");
    int ar_size = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("arr elements: ");
    T arr[] = (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, ar_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
        arr[i] = clazz.cast(in.next());
    }
    return arr;
}
```

UPDATE: but Scanner.next always returns a String, so I'm afraid You'll have to test the class to know which method of Scanner to use:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
        Object elem = null;
        if (clazz == Byte.class) {
            elem = in.nextByte();
        } else if (clazz == Short.class) {
            elem = in.nextShort();
        } else if (clazz == Integer.class) {
            elem = in.nextInt();
        } else if (clazz == Long.class) {
            elem = in.nextLong();
        } else if (clazz == Float.class) {
            elem = in.nextFloat();
        } else if (clazz == Double.class) {
            elem = in.nextDouble();
        } else if (clazz == BigInteger.class) {
            elem = in.nextBigInteger();
        } else if (clazz == BigDecimal.class) {
            elem = in.nextBigDecimal();
        } else if (clazz == Boolean.class) {
            elem = in.nextBoolean();
        } else if (clazz == String.class) {
            elem = in.next();
        }
        arr[i] = clazz.cast(elem);
    }
```